# Natbib error with Journal of Complex Networks (OUP)

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm submitting a paper to the Journal of Complex Networks (An Oxford University Press journal).  They provide their LaTeX class files at [this page](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/comnet/for_authors/).

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR: Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

Problem - I seem to be following the steps that they provide.  Based on their instructions in the sample .tex file, I am compiling:

```
\documentclass{comnet}

\begin{document}


\cite{Ahn1983}

\bibliographystyle{comnet}
\bibliography{sample}
%
% once the .bbl file has been generated then place the text in your article.

\end{document}
```

(`sample.bib` is provided in the link I gave above)
The `.bbl` file is just

> \begin{thebibliography}{00}
>
> \bibitem{Ahn1983}
>   Alexander, J.~C. {\&} Auchmuty, G. (1983)  Iterative methods for linear
>     complementarity problems with upperbounds and lowerbounds. {\em Mathematical
>     Programming}, \textbf{26}, 265.
>
> \end{thebibliography}

Following the instructions I copy and paste this in and recompile

```
\documentclass{comnet}
\begin{document}

\cite{Ahn1983}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\bibitem{Ahn1983}
Alexander, J.~C. {\&} Auchmuty, G. (1983)  Iterative methods for linear
  complementarity problems with upperbounds and lowerbounds. {\em Mathematical
  Programming}, \textbf{26}, 265.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

which compiles, but gives the error:

> ERROR: Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

Any thoughts on why this error exists, and more to the point, whether it's fixable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The document class file `comnet.cls` contains the following instructions, starting at line 1306:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{a}{,}{;}
```

The `a` in the fourth argument of `\bibpunct` instructs `natbib` to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. However, the bibliography style file `comnet.bst` is *not* compatible with authoryear-style citation call-outs.

(Aside: My hunch is that that the letter `a` in the `\bibpunct` instruction was chosen by mistake. For sure, the "instructions for authors" clearly state that numeric-style citation call-outs should be used.)

If you need to use the `comnet` bibliography style and are OK with numeric-style citation call-outs, I suggest you provide the following instruction in your document's preamble:

```
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{,}{;}
```

Comment: Mico's answer worked for comnet. Thank you!

Comment: @Ulgen - Thanks for the feedback! It's good to know that an answer I posted nearly 9 years ago is still useful.